# Specified Departments? - SQL

Tags: sql, join

imagine I have two tables, the "departments" table and the "employee" table.
This employee table has a column for "category".

I'd like to make a query for selecting departments that only have a specified type of employees.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far

Comment: What DBMS? Query syntax and the preferred way to write queries depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform a join from your departments and employee table on whatever columns link these two tables together. In the where clause, you will specify what types of employees that you want.

This will return a row for each employee, which might not be what you want. You may use the distinct function on the important columns that you're looking for in the departments table to get the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct dept_id 
from employee
where category = 'cat1'
and dept_id not in (select distinct dept_id
                    from employee 
                    where dept_id <> 'cat1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dept_id
FROM departments
WHERE dept_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT dept_id
     FROM employee
     WHERE category_id != @specified_category)
```

This query assumes there are no departments with no employees, since it will also return those empty departments. If that's a problem, you can add:

```
AND dept_id IN (SELECT distinct dept_id FROM employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select d.id_department from departments d where not exists
(Select e.id_employee from employees e where e.category!=your_category and e.id_department=d.id_department)`   you also need to verify that department  has employees.